# My deceased Cuban father had an US citizenship, is there any benefit for me?

Tags: united-states, immigration

My father born in Havana, Cuba in the 40's and in '56 he immigrated to the US. I have a card of that time that says "This is to certify that was admitted to the United States as an immigrant on 9/22/56 and has been duly registered according to law. Commissioner of Immigration and Naturalization".

He passed in 1984, in Havana. My question is: I, as legit son of his born in marriage, do I have any benefits since he was an US citizen? Can I apply for an US Visa and later apply for citizenship? I have no clue whatsoever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume that you were not born in the United States, and that your mother was/is not a US citizen. If these assumptions are incorrect, the answer below does not apply.

A child born outside the United States to a US citizen and a non-US citizen will be a US citizen so long as the parent spent a certain amount of time physically present in the United States. For a child born before 1986 to gain US citizenship through a single parent, that parent would have had to spend 10 years total in the USA, of which at least 5 years were after the parent’s 14th birthday. So if your father was a citizen and lived in the US until at least 1966 or his 19th birthday (whichever was later), you would be a US citizen.

However, the document you describe does not prove that your father was a US citizen. Instead, it only proves that your father was admitted to the US as an permanent resident (a so-called “green card”). If your father did become a citizen, he would have received a  Certificate of Naturalization. This would be necessary to prove your father’s US citizenship and, by extension, yours.

Comment: Thank you sir. I assume green card along won't be enough for me to be a US citizen

Comment: @AramAlvarez:  That's correct.  The only ways to gain US citizenship by birth are to be born in the US, or to be born to a parent who is a citizen (not just a legal resident).

Comment: Someone gave a negative to a question that starts with “deceased father”!? Shame on you whoever you are.

Comment: @Aram Alvarez Is there a way for you to learn whether or not he also was a citizen?

Comment: @kisspuska:  Feel free to suggest edits or write you own answer if you think there's a better way to answer this.

Comment: @Michael Seifert Oh, I plused your answer, I found a -1 on the question though; can’t see the reason why.

Comment: @kisspuska:  I suspect it had to do with the "specific legal advice" close-vote it received.  I can see why someone might have thought that, but I tried to confine my answer to a description of the law on citizenship through descent and the difference between residency and citizenship.

Comment: @Michael Seifert I see, yeah that makes sense. Still, probably could be reformulated in a Bob and Rob question. If the questioner is still in Cuba, it might have been a challenge to get this question out here at all. Translation, who has access to the internet so on and so forth. It wasn’t a very recent tragedy maybe for the better in this sense

Comment: @kisspuska I don't think we have any other documents from him...all I found is the green card and a passport. I tried to look up his A number in sites like USCIS but it is too complex to use.

Comment: @AramAlvarez  Generally US passports are not issued to non-citizens, so maybe he was a citizen after all.  Does the passport list his nationality?  Does it actually say "Passport" on the cover, or does it say "Travel Document"?  (The latter is what's sometimes issued to refugees who are not citizens.)